# Oracle remote connection without installing the oracle client

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, remote-server

Is there a way to connect to a remote oracle DB from a client PC without installing oracle on the client ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [download an ADO.NET driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) for Oracle. Here's a [step by step guide](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/cook-vs08.html).

Comment: Darin's answer is correct - just wanted to add that I found the ODAC xcopy packages listed at the links Darin gave to be particularly useful in the past. What I did was bundled the ODAC files into my MSI and then added an application environment variable to reference them. See this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clien

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install all of Oracle but only the ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends upon the remote server. If the remote server is not permitting remote access to db then u cannot access it anyway.Instead u need to build some sort of webservice and deploy that web service to the same remote server. And call the web service into your app.
The web service will act as a local app to db and will return your desired things, written in code. If its allowing remote access then as adviced above are good options.

I hope, you got it.