# Connecting to remote Oracle 10g DB without Oracle Client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, oracle10g, odbc

I am a J2EE Developer and have little knowledge of .NET. I am making a web service that connects to a remote Oracle DB. Now the problem is that I don't want to install oracle client on my system. Is it possible for me to connect to remote oracle DB without installing oracle client. I dont mind using odbc, oledb or any other way.
The configuration of my system and oracle DB are-

OS- Windows XP

IDE- Visual Studio 2008

Framework - .NET Framework 3.5

Oracle DB to connect - Oracle 10g

Please don't close the question as already asked as the links here are dead. 
[Oracle remote connection without installing the oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005329/oracle-remote-connection-without-installing-the-oracle-client)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html).

Comment: This I can install on my machine. But what when I host my code on an online Windows Server. Are there windows servers available which have oracle instead or mssql.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect with [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) (Standard or Professional) using the Direct Mode: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?directmode.html.