# How to use EZCONNECT format without sqlnet.ora file for deployment

Tags: c#, oracle, deployment, odp.net

I have developed a windows forms Application which talks to an Oracle Server. I am using ODP.net and deploying using the bare minimum dlls, as given in the solution to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clien)

I wish to connect using teh connection string in EZCONNECT format, but I can't use it unless the method is present in sqlnet.ora file([As documented here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/featConnecting.htm#i1006259))
But given my deployment, I don't have the oracle client installed, or an Oracle home. How do I enable EZCONNECT format?

Or is there some other way to connect when deploying ODP.net applcations?

Comment: Seems like I was mistaken in assuming that it doesn't work. The documentation I had linked to was incorrect. It does work, when you use the EZCONNECT format, out of the box!!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the directory location of your sqlnet.ora file in an environment variable named TNS_ADMIN. The location does not have to be in an "oracle home" per se.

Answer (score 0):

The doc isn't exactly wrong, it just does not specify that it means "the SQLNET.ORA in the Database Oracle Home". It is not referring to the ODP.NET oracle home on the client side.