# How can I deploy a .Net Application that uses ODAC to a clean computer with a tsnames.ora file packaged with installer

Tags: .net, database, oracle, tnsnames

So here is the problem. This application I have uses ODAC components but I don't want to have to install oracle clients on all the computers the application has to be installed on. So I fallowed this article below:

[What is the minimal setup required to deploy a .NET application with Oracle client 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clie)

The article works well with computers that have some sort of oracle installed or at least tnsnames.ora is in the correct location. However on a fresh machine I receive the error ORA-12645: Parameter does not exist. I have tried packaging the tnsnames.ora along with sqlnet.ora but the .dlls can’t find them. The code below is where the error is coming from:

```
 g_Db.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=osw-rmoradev)(PORT=1523))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=RML3A))); User Id=RM_Level3;Password="passowrd";"
            g_Db.Open()
```

Any Ideas on how to package the .ora files will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems by setting the environmental variables for the program instance to the location of the .ora data files seems to have fixed the issue.

```
nvironment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "c:\Documents and Settings\" & currentUserName & "\Local Settings\Apps\2.0;" + "c:\Documents and Settings\" & currentUserName & "\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data\\R5MG416O.62T\77DKVOW4.TWH\rct...tion_7a1a328dbe52217b_0002.0000_f2dbb34fd1c05e8d\Data;", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_HOME", "c:\Documents and Settings\" & currentUserName & "\Local Settings\Apps\2.0", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

Comment: However you will need to create environmental paths for each operating system. I will set the answer after some more testing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing the client, have you tried using the Oracle Data Provider?  I remember stumbling upon this project and then not needing to install the Oracle client.  [Link to ODP](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/InstallODP.htm)