# Oracle.DataAccess version could not load

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I am having trouble with `Oracle.DataAccess` in `WPF`. I used `Oracle.DataAccess v4.0`
without any problems. But now it updated to version 4.112 and when I add reference to this version in `WPF` the designer could not be loaded. It gives me the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, 
Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Please note that program runs without any problem. I read that it can be due to "target cpu" in properties. I tested both x64 and x86 but nothing changes. How can I solve this problem.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with my **Oracle.DataAccess.dll** file. I have downloaded **ODAC 11 XCopy** and copied Oracle.DataAccess.dll from \odp.net4\odp.net\bin\4 to my OracleClient's \odp.net\bin\4 folder and replaced dlls. Now it works like a charm.

Hope it will be helpful to someone else

Comment: hi, Adil. which version of ODAC 11 XCopy u did downloaded? I tried with ODAC 11 XCopy Release 5 and it's now work for me

Comment: Hi @JackDaniel. I am glad that it worked for you. I am sorry, but I don't remember now

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue I solved by putting dependencies DLL to Oracle.DataAcces. check this link [What is the minimal setup required to deploy a .NET application with Oracle client 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clie)

Hope It should help.

Comment: What should I do? Copy all this ddls to all of my WPF applications?

Comment: Yes. Put it in application Debug or Release folder. No need to reference it only required to put with Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But they don't  talk about WPF design mode they are talking about Deploying or setting up program. But I will try. Hope it will help

Comment: Yes. link talking about Deploying. I created application in WinForm. I faced same issue like your. but after putting dependencies dlls It's worked perfectly. try by putting dlls.

Comment: you can find dlls in OraHome\BIN

Comment: I did what is written. But I can't find oraociicus11.dll anywhere. And there is no change in my project

Comment: I don't know exact location right now. I m with different PC right now. you can try to search oraociicus11.dll in your operating system drive. Hope you can find. and Thanks for above solution I will also try with my old application.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problems way too many times. Below is some PowerShell that I routinely use to deploy an app.

```
$target = "\\SERVER\c$\PROJECT"
$oracleBin = "C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\"
$projectHome = "C:\Users\USER\Code\CSharp\PROJECT\bin\Release\"
$files = @(
($oracleBin + "oci.dll"),
($oracleBin + "orannzsbb11.dll"),
($oracleBin + "oraocci11.dll"),
($oracleBin + "OraOps11w.dll"),
($projectHome + "EntityFramework.dll"),
($projectHome + "EntityFramework.xml"),
($projectHome + "Oracle.DataAccess.dll"),
($projectHome + "PROJECT.exe")
#,($projectHome + "PROJECT.exe.config")
)
foreach($f in $files) {
    copy-item $f $target
}
```

Two notes I can add for someone struggling to solve this problem:

1. You can find the correct Oracle home (i.e. where your client_1\bin is), based on where you're referencing Oracle.DataAccess.dll from within Visual Studio. I have multiple Oracle homes so that's been an issue I've had to overcome a few times.
2. The above works for Oracle 11g. If you have Oracle 12c, I believe a similar process will work, but some of the file names change from *11.dll to *12.dll.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to download and execute the install.bat file in 'ODAC112030Xcopy.zip' from [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).