# Minimal .Net Oracle Client for a web application

Tags: .net, oracle, web, client

The following question is excellently answered and works well for a windows forms application but I cannot seem to get a minimal Oracle client install to work with a web application.  The DLL files are placed in the "executable" folder, i.e., the bin folder but it seems to be using my installed oracle client instead of the inline oracle client.

I also have a tnsnames.ora file in the application bin folder and it is not using this.

[What is the minimal setup required to deploy a .NET application with Oracle client 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clie)

Comment: They are unmanaged DLLs from the Oracle installation, they cannot be added as references.  I'm trying to work with a Clientless installation as described in the question I linked to.

Comment: I didn't mention ODP.NET.  I'm talking about the OCI client tools which are unmanaged dlls.  Please read the link to the similar answer I quoted in my question.

Comment: I am using Oracle.DataAccess but trying to get it to recognise the unmanaged Oracle OCI dlls in my installation folder instead of trying at access any installed oracle client.  As I say in my question, this works with a windows forms application but I cannot seem to get it to work with a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Clients will use the registry to find their associated DLL's (of which there are many). The best, best, way to use an Oracle Client is to install the Drivers and then let the .NET wrapper find them. Trying to do anything else is going to end in failure.

One of the problems Oracle clients have is that when installed they don't always set the permissions on the installation folders correctly. I have has Web-sites fail due to this many many times. Check the installation folders allow the IIS identity access to them.

Comment: I'm trying to package the Oracle Client files with my application so I do not need to deploy an oracle client.  Telling me this is not the best way does not help as in the environments I am deploying to I do not have the option of installing an Oracle Client.  My question is about providing the necessary files for the oracle client as in the question I quoted.  I don't therefore need or indeed want my application to have permission on any installed oracle client.