# Connect oracle from sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to create a generic Web service in SharePoint solution to connect any version of oracle, with simple Select, Insert, Delete and Update. The WSP should be deployed in SharePoint 2010.

As per my requirement I should not install any oracle client for connecting oracle so I am using `Oracle.DataAccess` dll.

I get the following issue while building the solution, may be because SharePoint 2010 support upto Framework 3.5.

The primary reference "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". OracleWebService2010.

I am stuck with this issue can anyone help me with this.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must use Oracle.DataAccess .NET 2.0 version.
If you have installed ODAC, you will find it here:

C:\app\ORAUSER\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\2.x

If you cannot install ODAC on target computer, then Oracle.DataAccess will still not be enough. Check this:
[What is the minimal setup required to deploy a .NET application with Oracle client 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clie)

Comment: Thank you for the Oracle.DataAccess .NET 2.0 version dll path it was useful to me