# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-config, assembly-references, odp.net-managed

In my website project built on .net 3.5, when I add reference to the **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll** by adding this in the web.config

```
<add assembly="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
```

it give this error

```
Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to     service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes at .net version 3.5
The solution is to upgrade the .net version to .net 4.0 or above

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded my project version to .NET 4.8 from .NET 4.5.2 and then
Installed the OracleManagedDataAccess nuget package into the solution (seems it wasn't installed)

This resolved the error.